# WTL CCommandBarCtrl imagelist (default and hot/disabled) ignored when set

Tags: ribbon, imagelist, wtl

I am trying to modify the images in a ribbon's Quick-Access-Toolbar but all my attempts seem to be in vain. I had the WTL-wizard create a simple ribbon-based application to start with. The wizard creates a CMainFrame with the a member var called 'm_CmdBar' of type 'CCommandBarCtrl'.

In 'CMainFrame::OnCreate()' the m_CmdBar is created with 'Create( m_hWnd, rcDefault, NULL, ATL_SIMPLE_CMDBAR_PANE_STYLE )' and the images are loaded with 'LoadImages(IDR_MAINFRAME)'. The images come from the default visual-studio provided 4-bit Bitmap toolbar-resource. If I leave 'LoadImages(IDR_MAINFRAME)' untouched, then the crappy 4bit icons are visible in the QAT.

Now, reading through the very sparsely only available WTL documentation (and Win32 API docu about about image lists) some people suggest to change the image list. I tried the following approaches (after commenting out 'LoadImages(IDR_MAINFRAME)' in order to start with a blank slate.).

1st attempt (load a 32Bit bitmap-strip with 5 16x15px consecutive icons):

```
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap( IDB_TEST32BPP );
WTL::CImageList imgList = m_CmdBar.GetImageList();
imgList.Create( 16, 15, ILC_COLOR32, 8, 1 );
imgList.Add( bmp.m_hBitmap, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) ); // also tried different masks
m_CmdBar.SetImageList( imgList );
imgList.Detach(); // also tried once without detaching
```

But to no avail. I tried to force the imagelist with:

```
m_CmdBar.SendMessage( TB_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)imgList.m_hImageList );
```

but it this did not work either.

2nd attempt is very much like the first, except that this time I changed the create call to:

```
imgList.Create( 16, 15, ILC_COLOR24 | ILC_MASK, 8, 1 );
```

in hope that maybe the loading code does not like 32bpp images... but again, no cigar (LoadBitmap was adjusted to load a 24bpp version of course). 3rd attempt was to simply reload the default images (4bit) so again I changed the create call to:

```
imgList.Create( 16, 15, ILC_COLOR4 | ILC_MASK, 8, 1 );
```

but you have guessed it... noting. And with nothing I actually mean, that the QuackAccess-Toolbar does reserve the space for the 5 buttons (as per the XAML ribbon config) but icons/images do not appear. The QAT-buttons are white but react to interaction. Trying to load the hot and disabled lists using the provided WTL-API also does nothing at all.

The only approach that worked somehow was to manually load every bitmap directly and linking it to its command with:

```
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap( IDB_ICON1_32BPP );
m_CmdBar.AddBitmap( bmp.m_hBitmap, ID_TEST_BTN );
```

works as long as the XAML config correctly provides an entry in the QAT section for ID_TEST_BTN. AddIcon also works but introduces an artifact (a black vertical 
 1px-bar, as if a right-frame was drawn for every icon. I guess it's the 16x16 versus 16x15 pixel problem).

I might be inclined to give up and go with the AddBitmap-workaround, but I'd like  the disabled and hot-version to work too, and there is no AddBitmap for that as it looks. Also, I guess there is no way to force an image to any of the QAT buttons via the XAML file???